# how to remove 2nd 0r 4th div padding with Pure CSS not jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using following jQuery to remove `padding-right` from 2nd or 4th or 5th div in a matrix or row & columns in responsive design.

I am using following

```
if (windowSize == 360) {
$("div.box-wrapper  > div:nth-of-type(2n+2)").css("padding-right", "0px");
}

if (windowSize > 300 && windowSize < 639) {
$("div.box-wrapper  > div:nth-of-type(2n+2)").css("padding-right", "0px");
}

if (windowSize > 639 && windowSize < 768) {
$("div.box-wrapper  > div:nth-of-type(3n+3)").css("padding-right", "0px");
}


if (windowSize == 768) {
$("div.box-wrapper  > div:nth-of-type(4n+4)").css("padding-right", "0px");
}

if (windowSize > 768 && windowSize < 801) {
$("div.box-wrapper  > div:nth-of-type(4n+4)").css("padding-right", "0px");
}
```

Now i want to achieve same by using CSS.

I tried following but this is not working

```
.box-wrapper :nth-child(2n+2)
{
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

for some reason it is not working

UPDATED CSS

```
@media (width:480px) 
{
.profile-item-inner-wrapper>div:nth-child(2)
{
padding-right:0;
}
}

@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width:639px)
{
.box-wrapper>div:nth-child(2)
{
padding-right:0;
}
}

@media (min-width:640px) and (max-width:767px)
{
.box-wrapper>div:nth-child(3)
{
padding-right:0;
}
}

@media (width:768px) 
{
.box-wrapper>div:nth-child(4)
{
padding-right:0;
}
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:799px)
{
.box-wrapper>div:nth-child(4n+4)
{
padding-right:0;
}
}

@media (min-width:800px) 
{
.box-wrapper>div:nth-child(5n+5)
{
padding-right:0;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us some sample html or a demo would be better.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jQuery code worked, then you can just use the same selectors in your CSS:

```
div.box-wrapper > div:nth-of-type(2n+2) {
  padding-right: 0;
}
/* add other rules */
```

To check for the dimensions of the viewport, you might wanna read about [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).